# I am looking for a graph layout that can separate communities in igraph Python

Tags: python, graph, visualization, igraph

I am trying to plot a graph with Python `igraph` and I want each communities in the graph to be clearly distinguishable just as the image in the link below(I am sorry that I cannot upload images.)

[image: Illustration: communities have different colors]
[I want to plot a graph like this](http://perso.uclouvain.be/arnaud.browet/img/G1.png)

However, all I can do with my best is

```
community = g.community_multilevel()
membership = community.membershiplayout = g.layout('kk')
plot(graph, 'test.png', layout = layout, vertex_color=membership,
palette=ClusterColoringPalette(len(set(membership)) + 3), vertex_size = 5)
```

and the result is not satisfactory because the vertices of different communities are mixed up..

Is there any graph layouts other than `'kk'` that emphasizes the communities of graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question for the R version of igraph:
[How to make grouped layout in igraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390221/how-to-make-grouped-layout-in-igraph)
I guess you just need to adapt it to the Python version.

Edit: actually, there's also an existing question for Python igraph: [Draw network and grouped vertices of the same community or partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184306/draw-network-and-grouped-vertices-of-the-same-community-or-partition/23185529#23185529)

Comment: thanks a lot vincent!